# Grepcode plugin for IntelliJ IDEA- can debugger be attached to third party library without source loaded into IDEA?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, ide, grepcode

I understand that when  when debugging in IntelliJ IDEA, it expects third party library ***source code***  being attached if we want to step into the code from third party libs.

Now having installed Grepcode plugin for IDEA (http://grepcode.com/intellij), using "Find on GrepCode.com" item of the "Tools" menu, it allows me to see the source code from a browser started by IDEA. However I could not get the debugger to step into 3rd party libs even with grepcode plugin. IDEA tells me "Source not found" then provides me link to "Download Source".

Maybe GrepCode IntelliJ Plugin is only supposed to view source, not debug yet. GrepCode FAQ or plugin page never says it can enable "debug stepping through third-party library" anyway.  Just want to double check if I missed anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think GC Plugin allows programmers to search/view the 3rd party libray by automatically starting a browser and return the search result for me. GC plugin is not able to get the debugger to step into 3rd party libs though.